# Flex application throws error when making http call (GET request)

Tags: apache-flex, http

I get following error occasionally while running my flex application. I dont know what is wrong as it works intermittently.

```
Error occured (mx.messaging.messages::ErrorMessage)#0
  body = ""
  clientId = "DirectHTTPChannel0"
  correlationId = "ACB1E8D4-51AF-21B9-E440-8ADBA0D4301E"
  destination = ""
  extendedData = (null)
  faultCode = "Server.Error.Request"
  faultDetail = "Error: [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: http://localhost/api/wireless/lookupNumber/6501234567/"]. URL: http://localhost/api/wireless/lookupNumber/6501234567/"
  faultString = "HTTP request error"
  headers = (Object)#1
    DSStatusCode = 0
  messageId = "21CFD7A0-209E-81E2-8416-8ADBAC4F6B69"
  rootCause = (flash.events::IOErrorEvent)#2
    bubbles = false
    cancelable = false
    currentTarget = (flash.net::URLLoader)#3
      bytesLoaded = 0
      bytesTotal = 0
      data = ""
      dataFormat = "text"
    errorID = 0
    eventPhase = 2
    target = (flash.net::URLLoader)#3
    text = "Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: http://localhost/api/wireless/lookupNumber/6501234567/"
    type = "ioError"
  timestamp = 0
  timeToLive = 0
```

Can you please guide me ?

Thanks

Comment: I think the "as it works intermittently" is throwing people off. Maybe you could describe a bit more what you're doing to test? How intermittent? This type of error could be a crossdomain.xml problem but it shouldn't be "intermittent" if it's that simple.

Comment: Hi did you get an answer for this question. I am also getting the same error message.

Comment: Managed to find a solution to this? We also get this. Specially when the client is making multiple concurrent requests.